# Load ManyToMany properties only in sonata admin view

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

i'm using sonata admin for managing entities in my symfony application. the entities have some many to many properties, and i want to administrate them in sonata. therefore i added this to the entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="farmer", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="farmerproduct",
 *     joinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="farmer_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   },
 *   inverseJoinColumns={
 *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *   }
 * )
 */
private $products;
```

The problem now is that in my application, I'm fetching lots of these farmers (the entity) and this ends up in a *PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted*

The reason is, I'm sending the results to the web application through JSON.

How can I use the products only in sonata admin only? I have already programmed some lazy loading style fetching of the products in a next step. So i don't need it in my webapplication.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the problem was easily solved

First Way to do is with the setIgnored method of the serializer: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#ignoring-attributes-when-serializing

If this does not work (as it didn't work for me), second way is:

Second way: Create a new entity object only for administration and add the manytomany in that entity, reconfigure your sonata admin config in admin.yml to work with the new entity which is mapped to the original entity in the database. Use your old entity for webapp.

Answer (score 0):

Was your problem in sharing the same actions for admin and web apps? If you have different logic in admin and web application, you can just create two different server bundles for them.

Comment: Nope it is not sharing the same actions for admin and webapps, its the problem that fetching the entities causes in a out of memory because the entities have lots of manytomany relations and i need these manytomany relations only in the sonata admin